# Is read() on a nonblocking socket "greedy" on platforms other than Linux (OSX, FreeBSD)?

Tags: c, macos, sockets, freebsd, nonblocking

Consider the following invocation of `read()` on a nonblocking stream-mode socket (`SOCK_STREAM`):

```
ssize_t n = read(socket_fd, buffer, size);
```

Assume that the remote peer will not close the connection, and will not shut down its writing half of the connection (the reading half, from a local point of view).

On Linux, a short read (`n > 0 && n < size`) under these circumstances means that the kernel-level read buffer has been exhausted, and an immediate follow-up invocation would normally fail with `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` (it would fail unless new data manages to arrive in between the two calls).

In other words, on Linux, an invocation of `read()` will always consume everything that is immediately available provided that `size` is large enough.

Likewise for `write()`, on Linux a short write always means that the kernel-level buffer was filled, and an immediate follow-up invocation is likely to fail with `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK`.

Question 1: Is this also guaranteed on macOS/OSX?

Question 2: Is this also guaranteed on FreeBSD?

Question 3: Is this required/guaranteed by POSIX?

I know this is true on Linux, because of the following note in the manual page for `epoll` (section 7):

> For  stream-oriented  files (e.g., pipe, FIFO, stream socket), the condition that the read/write I/O space is exhausted can also be detected by checking the amount of data read from / written to the target file descriptor.  For example, if you call read(2) by asking to read a certain amount of data and read(2) returns a lower number of bytes, you can be sure of having exhausted the read I/O space for the file descriptor.  The same is true when writing using write(2).  (Avoid this latter technique if you cannot guarantee that the monitored file descriptor always  refers  to  a  stream-oriented file.)

EDIT: As a motivation for the question, consider a case where you want to process input on a number of sockets simultaneously, and for whatever reason, you want to do this by fully exhausting in-kernel buffers for each socket in turn (i.e., "depth first" rather than "breadth first"). This can obviously be done by repeating a read on a ready-ready socket until it fails with `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK`, but the last invocation would be redundant if the previous read was short, and we knew that a short read was a guarantee of exhaustion.

Comment: Question 4: Is this guaranteed on Linux? Question 5: What is actually guaranteed? What is your problem? What other behaviour could actually occur?

Comment: As I stated, I believe it is guaranteed on Linux, and that this guarantee follows from the mentioned note in the `epoll` man page. If you have reason to believe I am wrong, please explain.

Comment: "believe" is a bad basis for programming. However, I don't see what other behaviour could occur and what change it would make to the application logic. You want data, you poll&read it. There is no guarantee two adjascent `read`s will execute back-to-back on a preemptive multitasking system. Your application always should assume data arrived instantly after `read` returned.

Comment: @Olaf I appended a note about why I think this question is relevant. Did you understand it?

Comment: @Olaf I understand your point of view. When working with level-triggered polling, one would often not care about this, and simply perform one read per read-readiness notification. In the edge triggered case, however, one has to exhaust kernel buffers to get new notifications, and you have to decide whether you want to do that in a "depth first" or "breadth first" fashion. In particular for the "depth first" case, it is relevant to try to eliminate one invocation of `read()`.

Answer (score 1):

It is guaranteed by [Posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recv.html):

> data shall be returned to the user as soon as it becomes available.

... and therefore on all the other platforms you mention as well, and also Windows, OS/2, NetWare, ...

Any other implementation would be pointless.

Comment: "available" is a wide field. I'd be quite pointless to artificially delay the data for any system.

Comment: @Olaf Exactly so.

Comment: @EJP I'm not quite sure what the intended meaning of that statement is, but I agree that it could be the guarantee that I am seeking.

Comment: @KristianSpangsege It *is* the guarantee you are seeking. It says that the data must be delivered if available. Ergo, only delivering some of it is not permitted. No mystery.

Comment: @EJP: I don't see which difference it would make for the application if there was no such guarantee. Internal processes in the OS can still delay the processing of frames.

Comment: @Olaf I don't know why you're addressing that comment to me. The first part sounds like a comment for the OP, and in any case it's irrelevant as there is such a guarantee. The second part isn't relevant to the question that was asked.

Comment: @EJP: I thought you had some idea I did not see. Just trying to understand the question. As you provided an answer, You seem to have understood it. OP apparently cannot clarify.

Comment: @Olaf It is relevant because it can save you a system call in a case where you want a "depth first" rather than a "breadth first" exhaustion behavior while servicing multiple sockets from a single thread.

Comment: @EJP I'm still not 100% convinced, but I see your point. There seems to be no alternative interpretation that would make sense, at least not a lot of sense :-).

Comment: @Olaf It seemed to me that both you and I understood the question. If you didn't, you should seek clarification from the OP, and not under this answer, and not by introducing extraneous material.

Comment: @EJP I suppose you believe that an implementation, that would artificially limit reads to some fixed size that is lower than the kernels receive buffer, would be a violation of POSIX requirements.

Comment: @KristianSpangsege I cannt understand your difficulty. Data in the socket receive buffer is available, by definition. *Ergo* it must all be delivered immediately, as per Posix. There's nothing not to understand.

Comment: @EJP: I did with my very first comment on the question itself. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Olaf So what are you doing under here? Comments under an answer should be relevant to the answer.

Comment: @EJP Consider an implementation that would artificially limit reads to some fixed size that is lower than the kernels receive buffer. Am I right in assuming that this would be in violation of POSIX requirements according to your understanding?

Comment: KristianSpangsege *Any* implementation that didn't deliver all the data that was available would fail the Posix requirement I quoted. This applies to any special case you can construct. I am not going to answer them all one by when when a general answer already exists. You don't need to keep asking the same question over and over again.